# iOS app closes immediately after launch when accessing code from the Binding Library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, rfid, xamarin.ios-binding

I am facing a strange issue. I have converted the Native framework ([Serialio RFID reader](https://serialio.com/product/rfid-nfc-hardware/products-rfid-nfc-hardware-idchamp-brand-readers-nfc-readers-writers-2)) into Binding Library and using it in one of my samples. This sample has only one ViewController. Problem is, app launches in Simulator but it closes immediately in the real iPad device, based on if I write the following line or not.

```
public partial class SViewController : UIViewController
{
    public SViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    //If I comment following one line, it launches in the iPad too.
    //If uncomment, app closes immediately after launch.
    //In Simulator this has no issue. It launches.        
    SerialioDeviceManager sdm = SerialioDeviceManager.DefaultManager;

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        //Even if I comment out above Initialization and write that line here, it doesn't allow app to launch in iPad.
        SerialioDeviceManager sdm = SerialioDeviceManager.DefaultManager;
    }
}
```

**iPad Device Log:**
[image]

**Few More Details:**

- App is closed even before this ViewController is called/initialized.
- This happens in `DEBUG` as well as `RELEASE` mode.
- Supported architecture is `ARMv7 + ARM64`
- Linker Behaviour : Link Framework SDKs Only
- Native SDK sample runs perfectly.
- This Framework required iPhoneos10.3 SDK while conversion.

**EDIT:**

Just to update, I am using the following file in the Binding Library.

[image]

Am I correct?

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like your framework doesn't support real device ,check it by `lipo -info yourlib.a` , and what does this word mean `Supported architecture is ARMv7 + ARM64` ,is it for the Project or framework?

Comment: @ColeXia : Thanks for your response. Architectures in the fat file are: armv7 arm64. The one which I mentioned is the Architecture which I set in the Visual Studio for Mac for the Sample Project, iOS Build setting which uses the binding library.

Comment: It's weird , Architecture  `armv7+ arm64`  is used to real device.... but it works on the simulator instead of your ipad..

Comment: Yeah it's weird. I have Edited my Question, just to make sure If I am correct in a way using the .a File from inside the Framework.